# How it is possible to add numbers between 0-9 (Example) if i add 4 with 0 output should be 4, if i add 4 with 8 output should 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

The numbers are from 0-9
if i give a number 5 output should be 9 which is 5+4, when it comes to 6 output should be 0 and for 7 output should be 1

Comment: How is it possible to add numbers? `a+b`

Comment: Please read [ask]. The clearer you are, the more likely you are the get a helpful response.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to use integers modulo 10 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)).

```
def mod_add(a,b):
    return (a+b) % 10

>>> mod_add(4,8)
2

>>> mod_add(5,4)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def mod_add(a):
     return (a+4) % 10
print(mod_add(7))
>>> 1
```